# is there a standard dialog for 'app does not have access to your photos'?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Is there a standard UIView/controller/dialog provided in iOS SDK for **informing the user the app does not have access to X resource and this can be fixed from iOS privacy settings.**

I have noticed a **consistent** view seen in many apps (snapshot below is taken from Viber). I could not find any API that would give me this dialog. I suppose I can just create one but still wanted to double check?

For the particular case I have I want to alert the user if app does not have access to user **calendar**/ **reminders**.

(I have a BOOL result in my code that tells me access granted true/false -I have to next alert the user with appropriate UI.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public API's `UIImagePickerController` displays that view if the app doesn't have access to the user's photo library.  It's a `_UIAccessDeniedView`, which is a private class.

As far as I know, the public API doesn't provide an event picker controller, so there's no way to make the system display a similar “standard” view for calendars/reminders in your app.

If you want to set up a similar view yourself, you can extract the lock image using the [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor); it's named “UIAccessDeniedViewLock.png”.  Warning: copyright infringement.  Will Apple care?  I have no idea.

Comment: thanks! It seem there is no such picker for iOS reminders - which would then be accompanied with a similar dialog/view. I guess i can just create my own :)

Answer (score 0):

This interface can appear for the calendar if you use `EKEventEditViewController`.